# Getting an interface reference inside a lambda function

Tags: java, android, lambda, kotlin, functional-interface

Consider the following code:

```
val hwnd = Handler()
hwnd.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run()
            hwnd.postDelayed(this, 5000)
        }
}, 5000)
```

This way, I can post the same Runnable to the Handler by using `this` (which refers to the Runnable) in the `run()` method. But how could I do the same using only a lambda expression?

```
val hwnd = Handler()
hwnd.postDelayed({
    //How to get "this" here?
}, 5000)
```

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since default lambda conversion gives you lambda with signature of `() -> Unit`, that means underlying `Runnable` is completely hidden.

You have to either deal with manual object creation, or write a wrapper extension function  that will consume lambda with another signature:

```
// custom extension function for handler
inline fun Handler.postDelayed(delayMilis: Long, crossinline runnable: (Runnable) -> Unit) = postDelayed(object : Runnable{
    override fun run() {
        runnable(this)
    }
}, delayMilis)
```

Then at calling side you will be provided with `Runnable` object as lambda parameter (only parameter: `it`):

```
hwnd.postDelayed(5000){ 
    // it : Runnable
    hwnd.postDelayed(it, 5000)
}
```

Or if you want to get really fancy, change extension parameter to `Handler.(Runnable) -> Unit`, then you will be able to call:

```
hwnd.postDelayed(5000){ 
    // this : Handler, it : Runnable
    postDelayed(it, 5000)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible like that. You can refer to [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-this-accessible-in-sams/1477): *Is “this” accessible in SAMs?*

> `this` in a lambda refers to the instance of the containing class, if
>   any. **A lambda is conceptually a function, not a class, so there is no
>   such thing as a lambda instance to which `this` could refer.**
>
> The fact that a lambda can be converted into an instance of a SAM
>   interface does not change this. Having `this` in a lambda mean different
>   things depending on whether the lambda gets SAM-converted would be
>   extremely confusing.

You can create a workaround (for example as suggested in the discussion): Create an extension function:

```
inline fun runnable(crossinline body: Runnable.() -> Unit) = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() = body()
}
```

then you can call it like

```
hwnd.postDelayed(runnable { hwnd.postDelayed(this, 5000) }, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to the "qualified this" as described here:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html